# QWC2 Problems with Performance

Tags: qgis, performance, qgis-server, speed, qwc2

We have installed the QWC2 on a win server. The own geodata are in a PG database and the WMS for the QWC2 is generated by QGis-Server. So far everything works, but we have significant performance problems. Loading our own data takes several seconds. When I look at the server resources, the server is running at full load on one request.

Should 3.19GHz be sufficient?

Is it possible that something is obviously configured incorrectly or do I really need more CPU power from your experience?

Or what can I optimize in the settings?

I have already reduced the "Quality of the JPEG images" in the QGIS server to 10 (from 100).

[image]

Comment: Hi, I thing it would be benficial if you provide a bit mor info on the data you are loading (size etc.). Even though the specs of your WS look pretty sufficient to me.

Comment: Thanks. The Dataset are lines and points Energy-Network from Berlin over 30x30km and the ALKIS-Dataset for Berlin (parcels, buildings, numbers and streets) with informations from the PG-Database. No aerial images